# How to open the profiling menu in android TVOS in react native?

Tags: react-native, television

I am working on android TV OS in react native.I am trying to open the profiling menu but the menu cannot be opened from a remote.Is there any way to open the menu like how we shake or use (ctrl + m in windows or ctrl + D in mac) to open the menu in android TVOS.

Answer (score 0):

Dev Menu support: On the simulator, cmd-M will bring up the developer menu, just like on Android. To bring it up on a real Android TV device, press the menu button or long press the fast-forward button on the remote. (Please do not shake the Android TV device, that will not work :) )

Source: [Facebook Github](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv)